# google cloud message send notification but my device is never pushed

Tags: java, php, android, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to make a web app with push notifications. I'm using server key with no ip adress filtering so any ip is allowed (when I was adding my public shared ip from my server I was getting a 404 forbiden error...)
Now it looks like it works, when I send a message I get this :

```
{"multicast_id":768704xxxxx3856470,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1430054xxxxxx71%60cd63d3f9fd7ecd"}]}{"registration_ids":["APAxxxea-Q0s5pbFZHpSu4BfKdabxxxxxxxxWjPGItVSc54U6_t7WsJme5Z5UjYldhry66rTHk95CUcRR7m2iAtfvPgTklbWlHn4YiDZi1Qxxxxxxxg9iz5jKMPiulvIQTTM5F16THVjw"],"data":{"message":"New content available!"}}
```

But I never receive a push in my device. I've been following tutorials form google and also form StackOverflow answers, but I'm still very noob in android and I'm sure there is something wrong in my code and I can't figure out what it is,  any help would be greatly appreciated.

main activity:

```
    package com.example.alfredo.webapp;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    String SENDER_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";

    /**
     * Tag used on log messages.
     */
    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
    private WebView myWebView = null;

    TextView mDisplay;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;
    String regid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "hola coño");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialize variables
        context = getApplicationContext();
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        prefs = getPreferences(0);
        mDisplay = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

        // web view
        this.myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://mongini.net/guiasdelsur");

        //remove shared prefs
        /*
        SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.commit();
        */
        /*
        SharedPreferences clear_cache = getSharedPreferences("registration_id", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = clear_cache.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.commit();
        */


        // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with
        //  GCM registration.
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
                Log.i(TAG,"ok");
            }
            } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");

        }
    }



    // You need to do the Play Services APK check here too.
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkPlayServices();
    }

    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {

        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "This device is not supported.");

                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
        /**
         * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
         * <p>
         * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
         *
         * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
         *         registration ID.
         */
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing registration ID is not guaranteed to work with
        // the new app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
     */
    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the registration ID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    /**
     * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
     */
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
     * <p>
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * shared preferences. com.example.alfredo.webapp.MainActivity
     */
    private void registerInBackground() {

        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {

                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);


                    msg = "Device registered, registration id=" + regid;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                    // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();


                    // Save the regid for future use - no need to register again.
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regid);
                    editor.commit();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;
            }
            // Once registration is done, display the registration status
            // string in the Activity's UI.
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute();
    }



    private String readStream(InputStream is) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int i = is.read();
            while(i != -1) {
                bo.write(i);
                i = is.read();
            }
            return bo.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP
     * or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the
     * device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes back the message
     * using the 'from' address in the message.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
        // Your implementation here.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://www.mongini.net/android.php?host=localhost&dbname=bdapp&user=user&pass=pass&idPush="+regid);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            /** Connecting to url */
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            readStream(in);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception url ", e.toString());
        }finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

    }


    /**
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * {@code SharedPreferences}.
     *
     * @param context application's context.
     * @param regId registration ID
     */
    //aqui peta
    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }



    public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    GcmIntentService.class.getName());
            // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
            startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
    }


    public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
        public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        public GcmIntentService() {
            super("GcmIntentService");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
            // in your BroadcastReceiver.
            String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

            if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
                if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                            extras.toString());
                    // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                    // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                                + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    // Post notification of received message.
                    sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                }
            }
            // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
            GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }

        // Put the message into a notification and post it.
        // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
        // a GCM message.
        private void sendNotification(String msg) {
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                    .bigText(msg))
                            .setContentText(msg);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }



    //back device button
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            this.myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alfredo.webapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <permission android:name="com.example.alfredo.webapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.alfredo.webapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver
            android:name=".MainActivity$GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        </receiver>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="com.example.alfredo.webapp" />
            </intent-filter>



    </activity>




    <service android:name=".MainActivity$GcmIntentService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alfredo.webapp"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be hard to find the real solution without fixing your BroadcastReceiver implementation first.

It looks like you are following a deprecated sample. In the manifest, you no longer need the `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` action. Also, your receiver tag/entry should be outside the activity tag, and it should have an intent filter (your intent filter is outside the receiver tag).

Hope this leads you to a solution. You might want to follow [this](https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/master/gcm-demo-app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) sample code instead.

Comment: link to "this" sample code is dead. anyway google made some major changes on GCM at the end of May (2015), and now support even sending data to iOS devices

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I changed the link. Happy coding, guys!